# How to configure multiple orm mappings doctrine outside the bundle

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping

i have project having two folder one is symfony and another is my project i extend symfony to project folder and set mappings from project folder what i need i need multiple mappings for doctrine orm

my requirememt is i have a class (not a entity) `SuperClass` for same properties which i extends to Entity files so i need to define class in mappings as well

i doctrine they said mappings:

```
                # An array of mappings, which may be a bundle name or something else
                mapping_name:
                    mapping:              true
                    type:                 ~
                    dir:                  ~
                    alias:                ~
                    prefix:               ~
                    is_bundle:            ~
```

how to define multiple i did but not working

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
# not working one time only one mapping working i need to both will work
      Project\Component\User:
        is_bundle: false
        type: xml
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/orm-mappings/doctrine'
        prefix: 'Project\Component\User'
        alias: Project\Component\User
        mapping: true
# this is working
      Project/User:
        is_bundle: false
        type: xml
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/orm-mappings/doctrine'
        prefix: 'Project/User'
        alias: Project/User
        mapping: true
```

My `SuperClass` mappings not working only. if i move my file to in this `Project/User` then they bind properly and working but i need file put separate

Comment: You are using "\" and "/" in each config. Maybe that?

Comment: improve formatting

Answer (score 0):

Worked i have create one more folder for mapping `SuperClass` so now i have two dir and two different namespace as well

```
mappings:

  Project\Component\User:
    is_bundle: false
    type: xml
    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/orm-mappings/mapping-superclass'
    prefix: 'Project\Component\User'
    alias: Project\Component\User
    mapping: true

  Project\User:
    is_bundle: false
    type: xml
    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/orm-mappings/doctrine'
    prefix: 'Project\User'
    alias: Project\User
    mapping: true
```

this will work for you one namespace for db mapping which is `Project\User` and `SuperClass` namespace is `Project\Component\User`

Comment: For people reading this in a rush and trying to figure out the difference: Note that the problem was that both mappings were pointing to the same dir (see the dir config). Change that and you will fix the problem.